# PhoneGap Sql with PhonGap developer App

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

first at all thanks for reading.

I have a doubt, if i create a default phonegap application with the phonegap developer app (to connect wireless with my phone to see the changes) and then i add the plugin of sql lit to my config.xml and create the basic code to populate a database and insert two rows.

If i see the app in my w8 with phonegapp developer app should works the database queries and those things??

Cause now seems nothing works and i'm confuse. I add the following line in the config.xml to add sql lite plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="com.millerjames01.sqlite-plugin" version="1.0.1" />
```

This is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Soccer Player</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="deviceready" data-role="content">
         <ul id="SoccerPlayerList">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "1.0", "Just a Dummy DB", 200000); //will create database Dummy_DB or open it
var app = {

initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};


//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerPlayer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Club TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
}

//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
    db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
}

//select all from SoccerPlayer
function queryDB(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SoccerPlayer',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx,result){
    $('#SoccerPlayerList').empty();
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index);
        $('#SoccerPlayerList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Name']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Club '+row['Club']+'</p></a></li>');
    });

    $('#SoccerPlayerList').listview();
}
```

Comment: Currently you cannot add third-party plugins with the developer app. It is built only with the core plugins installed.

Comment: so i should build the apk for example and test it in android phone or emulator isnt?

Comment: correct. As far as I can tell, the developer app is for testing the display of your app, not the specific functions. To do that you need to create your own build and deploy so that all of the native plugin code will be included with the build. The developer app paired with `phonegap serve` just servers the HTML/JS/CSS to the app so you dont have to rebuild and deploy every time you add a div or a button or change a color.

Comment: i will test it in android emulator. Thanks a lot, and another thing.. do you see any error in the code?? or should works fine?

Comment: It should work, but I would set the first line to `var db = null;` and then on the line before `db.transaction...` do `db = window.openDatabase...`  this will ensure the database is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the code. 
I solve it just building the app in the OS that i wanted, then in the included .js. I hope that my code help someone to get started with mobile phonegap apps =).

```
var db = window.openDatabase("haberes", "1.0", "Haberes DB", 10000000);
var app = {
initialize: function() {
  this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
  app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {
  db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
};

app.initialize();

function errorCB(tx, err) {
  alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
};


function successCB(tx) {
    alert('Successfully Query');
};

function isTableExists(tx, tableName, callback) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+tableName, [], function(tx, resultSet) {
      if (resultSet.rows.length <= 0) {
          callback(false);
      } else {
          callback(resultSet.rows.length);
      }
    }, function(err) {
      callback(false);
    })
};

function populateDB(tx) {

     isTableExists(tx, "perfil", function(status) {
              if (!status) {
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS perfil (id unique,prf_nombre,prf_apellido,prf_grado,prf_dni INT,prf_email)');
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO perfil (id,prf_nombre,prf_apellido,prf_grado,prf_dni,prf_email) VALUES (1,"Gaston","Dedieu","Coronel",36791591,"gastondedieu@hotmail.com")');
              } else{
                alert('Filas en tabla perfil '+status);
              }
          });


        isTableExists(tx, "haber", function(status) {
            if (!status) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS haber (id unique,hab_fecha,hab_neto REAL,hab_bruto REAL,hab_fecha_in TIMESTAMP,hab_prf_id)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO haber (id,hab_fecha,hab_neto,hab_bruto,hab_prf_id) VALUES (1,"24/02/2015",14256.65,19856.46,1)');
            } else{
                alert('Filas en tabla haber '+status);
            }
        });




      };
```